# How to remove null Values in a Table Header Objective C, Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am new to coding and have just started on working on a new app.  I have been stuck for a few days searching for answers on how to remove null headers in a table header.

This is my code at the moment:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *view=[DetailGroupHeader loadInstanceFromNib];
    NSDictionary *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:section];
    if ([[self.restaurant objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"] isEqual:[category objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"]]) {
        DetailGroupHeader *headerView=(DetailGroupHeader *)view;
        headerView.lblTitle.text=[category objectForKey:@"maincatename"];
        headerView.btnReveal.indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
    }
    return view;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return self.categories.count;
}
```

At the top of `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` I am initiating the names of the headers, and this part is working perfectly fine.
However when I get to the next function `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`, to count the number of headers I receive null values, how can I get rid of the null values in the header?

Comment: Where exactly do you receive null-Values? Is your array `self.categories` even initialized? Have you set a breakpoint to reveal the contents?

Comment: I received the null values in the header if the restaurant_id in self.restaurant doesn't match the restaurant_id in category restaurant_id.  Also not too sure how to set a breakpoint to reveal the contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *view=[DetailGroupHeader loadInstanceFromNib];
    NSDictionary *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:section];
    if ([[self.restaurant objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"] isEqual:[category objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"]]) {
        DetailGroupHeader *headerView = (DetailGroupHeader *)view;
        NSString *maincateName = [category objectForKey:@"maincatename"];
        if ([maincateName isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            maincateName = @"";
        }
        headerView.lblTitle.text = maincateName;
        headerView.btnReveal.indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I am still receiving blank headers with this.  In the self.categories.count function I have 482 records which it is counting.  If the restaurant_id matches I would like the blank headers to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making some really basic mistakes. As I can see you are only showing those rows which have `[[self.restaurant objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"] isEqual:[category objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"]]` condition true. But you are returning `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, count of complete `categories` array as `self.categories.count`

I will suggest you to check:

- Calculate count of header where condition `[[self.restaurant objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"] isEqual:[category objectForKey:@"restaurant_id"]]` satisfies
- Check if the condition you are working with really have it's existence, (print log or set break point)

That's all I can say for now. If problem persist, add log print of your `self.restaurant` dictionary and `self.categories` array.

Comment: What I want to do is that I want to count the number of results I  get when the restaurant_id from self.restaurant is the same as restaurant_id from category

Comment: Ok. That's exactly what I said!

Comment: Do you know how to do this as this is where I am stuck

Comment: Yes why not. Make a function, set a loop in it, create newArray, and add all record which satisfy your condition to newArray. And then make  newArray your table datasource.

Comment: Could you please assist me with some help on this through Skype, my id is jaw.khan